# Debian disables IRQs

Tags: linux, hardware

It's been two days that my Debian Wheezy 7 randomly disables IRQs apparently with no reason. After the IRQs are disables, I'm unable to mount hard disks and I have to reboot.

This is the output of syslog:

```
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438414] irq 18: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438419] Pid: 0, comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G           O 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 3.2.57-3+deb7u2
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438421] Call Trace:
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438422]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff81092bad>] ? __report_bad_irq+0x2c/0xb5
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438429]  [<ffffffff81092f6a>] ? note_interrupt+0x170/0x1f2
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438431]  [<ffffffff8109132c>] ? handle_irq_event_percpu+0x15f/0x17d
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438432]  [<ffffffff8109137e>] ? handle_irq_event+0x34/0x52
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438435]  [<ffffffff8106c189>] ? arch_local_irq_save+0x11/0x17
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438437]  [<ffffffff810936e1>] ? handle_fasteoi_irq+0x7c/0xaf
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438440]  [<ffffffff8100f9e1>] ? handle_irq+0x1d/0x21
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438442]  [<ffffffff8100f5ba>] ? do_IRQ+0x42/0x98
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438445]  [<ffffffff8134feee>] ? common_interrupt+0x6e/0x6e
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438446]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff811b0d34>] ? timerqueue_add+0x80/0xa0
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438450]  [<ffffffff811eec0d>] ? intel_idle+0xea/0x119
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438452]  [<ffffffff811eebec>] ? intel_idle+0xc9/0x119
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438455]  [<ffffffff81270851>] ? cpuidle_idle_call+0xec/0x179
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438457]  [<ffffffff8100d242>] ? cpu_idle+0xa5/0xf2
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438460]  [<ffffffff816abb36>] ? start_kernel+0x3b8/0x3c3
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438462]  [<ffffffff816ab140>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x140/0x140
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438463]  [<ffffffff816ab3c4>] ? x86_64_start_kernel+0x104/0x111
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438464] handlers:
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438487] [<ffffffffa00f5cfd>] ata_bmdma_interrupt
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438490] [<ffffffffa0051b0b>] sil24_interrupt
Jul 15 01:56:23 GC01SRVR kernel: [ 5358.438492] Disabling IRQ #18
```

What could be the source of the problem? What's the path to follow to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried adding `irqpoll` to your kernel command line? (Edit it in GRUB before booting).

Comment: Should I? I'm afraid that since the IRQs involved are the ones of the hard disks, the system won't boot.

Comment: Editing it from the grub prompt is temporary; it'll only last for one boot. So if it doesn't work, you just reboot and its back to the way it was before.

Comment: Cool! I'll google it and try it, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Is it correct if I add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet irqpoll"` to `/etc/default/grub`? Sorry if I ask but I'm afraid the system won't boot if I do something wrong.

Comment: That's how you make it permanent... Instead, just (when booting) in the grub menu, select the kernel, then hit edit. Edit the kernel command line there to add the `irqpoll` option. Then boot. (The other one isn't permanent either, you can always edit it off the command line for one boot.)

Comment: What changed two days ago? This is either a kernel bug or defective hardware. If you didn't change your hardware or upgrade your kernel recently, do a memory test (install the `memtest86+` package and boot to the “memory test” option, leave for at least one full pass) — RAM can go bad over time.

Comment: No hardware was added or removed. The IRQ changes affect only hard disks. It usually happens when I move large amounts of data among the many hard drives of my system (>300GB). I still have to try to enable irqpoll in grub. I'll post as soon as I can try that.

Comment: Ok, I cannot reproduce the error anymore. It did not occur in the last 24h so I cannot say if it is fixed or what. Thank you for your help anyway.